# How to set all images to equal width and height without stretching

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I set all images to have an equal size of 40x40 without stretching?

I tried to do the following but it did not work:

```
<style>
 .img-container {
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
 }

 .pic {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
 }
</style>

<div class="img-container">
    <img src="image_path" class="pic" />
</div>
```

I am forced to use `overflow: hidden` and it will basically crop half of it. Is there a way I can achieve equal width and height with jQuery or Bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think there is any way of doing that.

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are actually trying to do... If you have some picture with a size different that the desired target size but you do _not_ want to strech/shrink it and you _also_ do not want to crop it... then what _do_ you want to do with it?

Comment: @arkascha, Because I am developing a site where users can upload their profile pictures and I can not guess their image's dimensions.

Comment: Which does not answer my question at all, sorry. Again: what _do_ you want to do with the pictures to make them fit?

Comment: @Raymond, You can set the `.img-container` as `overflow: hidden` and no need to set any width or height in `.pic`. It will not stretch the image and display the portion of the image.

Comment: Sorry, mate. I'm afraid you are re-inventing the wheel. If you are "... developing a site where users can upload their profile pictures ..." I believe you should take advantage of a proper CMS. Take a look at this and see how Drupal handle user profiles. Out of the box. Good luck! https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/profile

Comment: @arkascha, Basically I want to achieve the same effect as what Facbook has when a user posts a status. You see their profile picture (that is 40x40) with their name next to it. So I thought a logical explanation would be wrapping the image tag with a div and making it take it's height and width.

Comment: It is really impossible since different images may have different sizes. However you can generate thumnails for each image of size 64*64 or 32*32 and store the image as image.jpeg, image_64 or image_32 whenever user uploads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure this isn't what you want? The image will scale to the container fine, and the spare space is filled by the container's background. Also, the image is centred perfectly, no matter what the dimensions.

```css
 .img-container {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   border: 1px solid;
   position: relative;
 }
 .img-container img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Random image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way achieving this with `<img>` tag, as changing initial image dimensions unproportionally will always lead to ugly image scaling. Instead you may find it more suitable here to use `background-image`

```
<div class="item"></div>

.item {
    background: url('path/to/your/image.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-backround-size: cover;
    backround-size: cover;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

It will not give you 100% desired effect, but at least you will be able to control your image container size nicely, and your image will still occupy all of it without changing aspect ratio.

**UPD**: In case of user profile pic you are discussing in the comments, you definitely need to look for more complex solution. And for sure it was already invented before you.

Comment: In many cases it is undesirable (from a SEO and semantic perspective) to use bg images. Think about screenreaders for instance. You need that alt tag of the image.

Comment: 100% true, but how you will make uploaded images (which will be of different dimensions) occupy all the container space without unproportional scaling?

Comment: Considering he/she accepted my answer I think they misphrased their question: it mustn't be *covered* it should just scale. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fully fill the container with an image without to stretch you have 2 options:

for **background-image** use: `background-size: cover;`

```css
#image {
outline: 2px solid red;
width: 550px;
height: 150px;
position: relative;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="image" alt=image></div>
```

for **regular images** use: `object-fit: cover;` plus `overflow:hidden` on the container. Use `object-position: 0% 0%;` for positioning.

```css
#img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: 0% 0%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#cover {
  width: 550px;
  height: 150px;  
  outline: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover"><img id=img src="http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All images that will have class pic will be of size 40px x 40px without stretching (ie.actual image size but will fill the area around it with white space)

```
.pic {
        width: 40px; //your image size
        height: 40px; //your image size

        /*Scale down will take the necessary specified space that is 40px x 40px without stretching the image*/
        object-fit:scale-down;
    }
```